# Get position of the circle in the image, circle is drawn on the camera while taking the image

Tags: android, opencv, resolution, screen-resolution

I've an image which has a object(circle) placed on it while taking a picture in an android app. The circle center on the camera is the mid of the screen height and width and circle radius is 10% of the image.

Now, in opencv, I want to get exact position of the cirlce. Dividing number of cols and rows by 2 won't give exact circle center nor 10% of the cols gives exact radius.

How can I get circle center and radius in pixels in opencv?

For a particular example, camera width is 1080 and height is 1704. Image width and height taken by the camera in pixels is 3120 and 4160. By taking half of the width and height would give me the circle ceter, which should be 1560, 2080 and center should be 210(10% of the image width). But this calculations differs from exact circle values on the image.

[image: Camera screenshot]
This is the circle placed on camera while taking the image. Every image taken would also have the circle too. I want to get this circle parameters in the image.

Comment: I'm really confused by the question. What is your expected input and output? To detect circles look for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform which i think is in openCV.

Comment: post a sample image please

Comment: @starmole Edited the question.

Comment: @Micka I can't use circle detection.

Comment: the white circle ist what you want to detect?

Comment: @Micka I don't want to detect it, I want to determine its parameters by simple calculations. i.e camera width to image pixels conversion

Comment: any reason why you don't want a detection? You said that image center and 10% of image size doesn't work to represent the circle, so you will need some kind of detection!?!

Comment: Yes, image center and 10% of the image size don't work, the reason could be that the circle is placed at the camera center by taking half the the screen width and I'm trying to get circle center by taking half of the image pixels(cols of cv mat). I think there is some problem with taking half of the image pixels as screen width(1080) and image pixels (3120) aren't same.  I think there must be some way to converting screen with to image pixels for exact circle center and radius.

Comment: Can you show us the result of your calculated circle? If you detect the location of the circle in your test image and compare it to your calculated parameters, it could give you some insight into where your calculations are going wrong.